# How to find directories with the name of specific length

Tags: linux, unix, find, name-length

How could I find directories with the name of specific length?
For example, I have bunch of directories which have length of the name equal to 33 chars ('a92e8cc611fdebcca3cf2fc8dc02c918', 'c442fb3f46d6c8bd17d27245290a9512' and so on). 
Does `find` utility accepts condition in form of the 'wc -c'? Or maybe some other utilities should be piped together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

few ways with GNU find

```
$ find . -type d -name "?????????????????????????????????"

$ find /path -type d -printf "%f\n" | awk 'length==33'
```

Comment: +1 but I think it should be "-type d" to find directories rather than files

Comment: find . -regextype posix-extended -type d -regex ".{5}"

Comment: aeh sorry, use 35 instead of 5. you need to count the leading "./"

Comment: note that -regex match on the whole path. Therefore using -regex will not work if i start to find from a directory like for example: find /path -regextype posix-extended -type d -regex ".{35}" and not current directory

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a Java tag, but if you did you'd write a FileFilter to encapsulate whatever criteria you have in mind and pass it to the java.io.File.list() method.  If you want to traverse the entire directory structure tree you'll have to recurse, but it's entirely doable.

Sorry, it's just not *nix scripting.

The Apache Commons IO JAR has some nice file and directory utilities that could make this an easy job.

Comment: i wouldn't want to use Java just for this. :)

Comment: Maybe not...I wrote 90% of it before I noticed the lack of a "java" tag, so I posted it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
find dir -name '?????????????????????????????????'
```

(that's 33 time `?`).

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'x=`basename {}`; [[ ${#x} == 33 ]] &&  echo $x ' \;
```

This might be slow based on number of files you have.

To clarify:
`${#x}` -> finds the length of a string and
`basename` -> finds the name of the final directory